# PHP multi dimensional array not working as intended

Tags: php, arrays

I want to create this response

```
'Points' => array(
    'Point' => array(
                    array(
                          'Type' => 'value',
                          'Zone'   => 'value
                    ),
                    array(
                          'Type' => 'value',
                          'Zone'   => 'value'
                    )
              )  
    )
```

My code gives me this:

```
array:1 [▼
  "Points" => array:1 [▼
    "Point" => array:2 [▼
      "Type" => 4
      "Zone" => "Front"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Which is very close, unfortunately de Points key is being overwritten anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

```
$pointsObject = array();
foreach ($points as $point) {
    $pointsObject['Points']['Point'] = array(
        'Type'  => $point->type,
        'Zone'  => $point->zone
    );
}

dd($pointsObject);
```

Comment: @JohnConde Yes I am aware of that but look at my expected result. Does this mean it's impossible to achieve this?

Comment: $pointsObject['Points']['Point'][] = `  <- that's what you're missing

Comment: You could be looking for `$pointsObject['Points']['Point'] [] = ` instead of `$pointsObject['Points']['Point'] =` to append instead of overwrite

Comment: @kharhys It works thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You are overwriting the value of $pointsObject['Points']['Point'] in every loop. For to avoid overwrite its value you should add [] at the end. Example:

```
$pointsObject['Points']['Point'][] = array(...);
```

That push new values into the array in every loop.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

Just add [] after ['Points']['Point']

```
$pointsObject = array();
foreach ($points as $point) {
    $pointsObject['Points']['Point'][] = array(
        'Type'  => $point->type,
        'Zone'  => $point->zone
    );
}

dd($pointsObject);
```

Comment: "Try this" does not make for a good answer. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)